# Returning "FromJS" state VS returning Plain JS object state in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In the `react-redux` [documentation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-immutablejs-with-redux), it is written in the PROS section of *immutable.js* that:

> Components will both re-render when they shouldn’t, and refuse to
> render when they should, and tracking down the bug causing the
> rendering issue is hard, as the component rendering incorrectly is not
> necessarily the one whose properties are being accidentally mutated.
>
> This problem is caused predominantly by returning a mutated state
> object from a Redux reducer. With Immutable.JS, this problem simply
> does not exist, thereby removing a whole class of bugs from your app.
>
> This, together with its performance and rich API for data
> manipulation, is why Immutable.JS is worth the effort.

Please elaborate following ambiguities with suitable small examples.

1. I'm not getting that what will be the case when a component will render when it shouldn't and not render when it should.
2. Also, I'm not getting that when should we use *Immutable.JS* while returning data from the reducer (It has pretty disturbing syntax). Why can't we simply return the simple plain JavaScript object? Please give example in layman terms.
3. In the documentation, I also read that we should AVOID `.toJS()` in `mapStateToProps`, then how should we access the state returned from reducer in the component if we should not use `.toJS()` in `mapStateToProps`?

Answer (score 1):

`Redux`, as well as `immutable.js` is an architectural complication. What kind of problem you are going to solve with `Redux`? If you already made up your mind regarding the state management tool and going to move in deep.

Immutability is mostly about the requirement to implement reducers as pure functions. Here `immutable.js` could help to "recompute" a reference to the whole state no matter what part of it is changed. But it is a bunch of immutable data structures. To feed them to virtual DOM you have to transform them `toJS`. Are you ready to pay for such runtime "check" with additional complications and possible performance issues.

Maybe it is better to configure ESLint to have compile-time checks of immutability everywhere in your code. I mean places like:

```
const state = { foo: { bar: { baz: 'plugh' } } };
state.foo.bar.baz = 'Do not do that cause React do not track such changes at all)';
```

Answer (score 0):

[BTW give Mobx a try](https://mobx.js.org/README.html)
Maybe it will be more suitable for you compared to Redux. It's less functional and more structural/classical